# Заполнение модели данных

Tags: c#, .net

У меня есть модель и данные в текстовом виде которые должны быть записаны в данную модель

```
public class UserModel
{
  public string FIO { get; set; }
  public string EmployeeId { get; set; }
  public string Title { get; set; }
  public UserModel Manager { get; set; }
}
```

Проблема в том что мне необходимо заполнить Manager такой же моделью, и для поиска данных я имею только FIO, как я могу сопоставить данные что бы они корректно заполнились? так как у каждого UserModel есть Manager

Comment: Просто если у юзера нет менеджера записывайте `.Manager = null`. Точнее он и так будет `null` по умолчанию.

Comment: @aepot меня больше интересует ни как Null а как заполнить собственно Manager, если у меня на руках только FIO этого менеджера

Comment: Например `user.Manager = new UserModel { FIO = "..." };`

Comment: @aepot в таком случае будет не ссылка а новый элемент списка, чего мне не надо

Comment: Вы планируете использовать EF core и вообще какое-то сохранение в базу? Потому что пока в вопросе не видно никаких предпосылок к сохранению в базу и можете использовать структуру более свободно.

Comment: @AK в базу я не планирую ничего заполнять, мне данные нужны для дальнейших расчётов. Просто я думал можно что то на подобие EFCore сделать и добавить ForeignKey оно само все подтянется. Но я просто слишком многово хочу)

Comment: Правильно, если бы у вас был EF (даже и не Core) вы могли бы указать prop int ManagerId и заполнять его, но раз у вас нет готовых механизмов - то вам придётся свои писать, как вы и сделали в ответе.

Answer (score 0):

Решил вот так. Добавил еще одно свойство ManagerModel и в него добавляю модель

```
foreach (var user in userModels)
{
    if (user.ManagerModel == null)
    {
        user.ManagerModel = userModels.FirstOrDefault(um => um.FIO == user.Manager);
    }
}
```

Comment: Эм-м... `FIO` - строка (string). `Manager` - объект (UserModel). Они никак не могут быть равны.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov да, это в первоначальном варианте. Мне пришлось переделать модель и сделать Manager - string и добавить ещё ManagerModel - UserModel

Comment: По id надо сравнивать, а не так. И ещё словарь использовать.